# UIScrollView returns (null)

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, null

I have a a UIScrollView that returns (null) after a action I have. I have set the correct properties and I have set it up correctly in interface builder (It's a IBOutlet). I also have sythesized it. However, when this NSLog I get NULL.

```
NSLog(@"theImageViewer: %@", theImageViewer);
```

Now the action is really long and it's like 200 lines but it doesn't modify theImageViewer at all. It also appears that some of my other NSMutableArray, but I can fix them by reinitializing them.

Please help! Thanks,

Coulton

Comment: You say that it is NULL after the action. I assume it is NULL before the action starts?

Comment: To clarify: Is it null inside the action method or at some other time?

Comment: After a little more searching, I can give you a little more information. It happens when it displays another view and that view controller calls this view controller to do this action, then it returns null. I did not release it in my dealloc, so that's not it... Thanks!

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your code, but I am going to assume that you aren't passing your pointers around correctly. Show us the code that creates and displays the second view controller, and show us the header for the second view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run your program under the debugger and step through "the action" line-by-line until you see what's (accidentally) clobbering the variable.

Comment: Just did. It's when the view disappears because another view comes in front of it. But I don't know what's causing that...

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a wild guess and posit that you have two different objects. One you're creating in a nib, where it's all hooked up to other objects, and another that you're creating with `alloc` in your code. If you log `self` in the different methods where the outlets are or aren't filled, is it the same instance in all of them?